# How do we can get date & time seperatly from a single datetime field in sqlserver

Tags: sql-server

I have few fields(empid,arrivaltime) in sqlserver. I want to get the query output as follows

```
79    08/11/2009     3:21PM
78    08/11/2009     3:19PM
98    08/11/2009     9:02AM
97    08/11/2009     9:00AM
96    08/11/2009     8:56AM
95    08/11/2009     8:53AM
```

please give me sql query for this.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the date/time formatters using the `CONVERT` function.

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ArrivalTime, 103) AS [ArrivalDate],
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), ArrivalTime, 8) AS [ArrivalTime]
```

Or, you can also use the [UDF given here](http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/08/14/sql-server-get-date-time-in-any-format-udf-user-defined-functions/) for formatting date/times by providing the format.

To get the time in AM/PM format, you'll have to tweak the code a little bit like this -

```
SELECT
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), ArrivalTime, 9), 13, 5) + ' ' +
    SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR(30), ArrivalTime, 9), 25, 2)
```

Reference: [SQL Server Date/Time Formatters](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/tips/date-formats.aspx)

Comment: Great! this is working... but it shows arrival time in 24hours format. i need it to be 12hours format such as 05:34AM

Answer (score 0):

Try function `DATEPART`. It works like this:

```
SELECT DATEADD(D, 0, DATEDIFF(D, 0, GETDATE()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT empid, CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),arrivaltime,101) as  
   date,CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),arrivaltime,108) as time FROM Table
```

This will display the result almost as mentioned above. The only thing I don't know is how to format the time to be displayed with AM/PM

Answer (score 0):

Use the following query to get the exact result as you want:

```
select empid, convert(varchar,arrivaltime,101), substring(convert(varchar,arrivaltime,100),len(convert(varchar,arrivaltime,100))-6,7)
```